# Cannot open file in subdirectory with ZipFile

Tags: python, python-zipfile

For whatever reason i cannot open or access the file in this subdirectory. I need to be able to open and read files within subdirectories of a zipped folder. Here is my code.

```
import zipfile
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Z:\\STAR'):
    for name in files:
        if '.zip' in name:
            try:
                zipt=zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root,name),'r')
                dirlist=zipfile.ZipFile.namelist(zipt)
                for item in dirlist:
                    if 'Usb' in item:
                        input(item)
                        with zipt.open(item,'r') as f:
                            a=f.readlines()
                            input(a[0])
                    else:pass
            except Exception as e:
                print('passed trc file {}{} because of {}'.format(root,name,e))
        else:pass
```

This code currently gives me the error:

```
File "StarMe_tracer2.py", line 133, in tracer
    if 'er99' in line:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback for your error.

Comment: By traceback do you mean the error that the terminal returned? It is in a try: block so the traceback would only give you my print statement. What other info do you need?

Comment: Remove the `try` block and show us the traceback after that.

Comment: You could temporarily `raise e` from that `except` so that you can see where the exception originates.

Comment: The Print statement that I am receiving is 

```passed trc file "insert-filename-here".zip because of a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```

Comment: Full traceback without try block:

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StarMe_tracer2.py", line 250, in <module>
    main()
  File "StarMe_tracer2.py", line 243, in main
    todo()
  File "StarMe_tracer2.py", line 236, in todo
    trclooper('Z:\\STAR')
  File "StarMe_tracer2.py", line 211, in trclooper
    a=tracer(data,name,root)
  File "StarMe_tracer2.py", line 133, in tracer
    if 'er99' in line:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```

Comment: I can not explicitly post my file architecture but the issue is "I presume" the fact that the file in question is nested in a subfolder of this zipped directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content read from the file object opened with `ZipFile.open` is bytes rather than a string, so testing if a string `'er99'` is in a line of bytes would fail with a `TypeError`.

Instead, you can either decode the line before you test:

```
if 'er99' in line.decode():
```

or convert the bytes stream to a text stream with `io.TextIOWrapper`:

```
import io

...

with io.TextIOWrapper(zipt.open(item,'r'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: Each of the elements in the ```dirlist``` variable are ```str``` when I check thier ```type()``` will this help me open the file itself at all or just help in identifying the file in the ```os.walk()```?

Comment: if I change ```zipt.open(item)``` to 
```zipt.open(item.filename)``` i still get the same error :(

Comment: Oops, fixed my answer according to the traceback in your comment.